Followup on VBA Clipboard
With reference to ExcelHero's elegant solution to Copy/Pasting in Excel to the Windows Clipboard (posted several years ago and copied here for reference):
Function Clipboard$(Optional s$)
    Dim v: v = s  'Cast to variant for 64-bit VBA support
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
    With .parentWindow.clipboardData
        Select Case True
            Case Len(s): .setData "text", v
            Case Else:   Clipboard = .getData("text")
        End Select
    End With
    End With
End Function

Two questions:
(1)  Is there any way to get other  "clips" in the Windows 10 Clipboard?
I have only been able to get the latest one.
For example,  I'd like to get latest Clip and the one immediately prior to it.
I tried to execute the Function to get more than one "Clip", but got the "top" clip repeatedly.
This may simply be a function of the way the Windows 10 Clipboard works, but I'd like to see any comments.
(2)  What is the reason for the CreateObject"htmlfile") call?  It seems (in my limited
testing) to work as well without it,  and I don't see the need for it in the Function.
I tried the Function without the call to CreateObject, and it worked OK.

"With reference to.....:  Are you referring to Copy text to clipboard with Excel 365 VBA ??  Note: you can create links like this using: this syntax: [some text](https://url....)
